# Complicated Rails query for reports with missing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, highcharts

### Background

I have a complicated dynamic survey engine in my app, as a result I store answers in rows in a response table (instead of in a big flat survey table). One of the type of questions I'm now generating reports on all people who answer questions that have a 1-5 scales (1 - very unlikely ... 5 very likely). I generate my reports out of a reports_controller and send JSON to any report pages using them.

I'm generating reports to show these in a highcharts column format. The problem I originally ran into was wanting to show an accurate count even if nobody answers that response (i.e. send a 0 count in JSON).

I spent a lot of time trying to think of an elegant way to do this, and ended up creating a default empty hash of zeros, then merging it with my answers if the answer text matches.

### My question...

Is there a **better way** to do this? It performs fine (on a small scale right now), but doesn't seem very readable and since the answer_text is string in the results `"1" => 3` instead of `1 => 3`, I have to use to_s to match the keys.

### ReportController

```
question = params["question"]
format = params["report_type"]

stats = ResponseItem.joins("join table1 on table1.id = table2.table1id "\
      "join table2 on table2.id = table1.table3id "\
      "join table4 on table4.table3id = table2.id") \
      .where("table2.question_text = ? and client_id IN (?)", question, @clients.map(&:id)) \
      .select("count(*), answer_text") \
      .group("answer_text").order("answer_text").count()

case format

  when 'likely1-5'
    scale = {1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3  => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0}
    scale.each do |k, v|
      if stats.key?(k.to_s)
        scale[k] = stats[k.to_s].to_s
      end
      report_collection.push scale[k].to_i
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you can simplify your code for the same basic approach with the following:

```
when 'likely1-5'
  (1..5).each do |k|
    v = stats[k.to_s] || 0
    report_collection.push(v.to_i)
  end
```

Comment: That certainly cleans it up a lot and gets rid of the extraneous hash. I was playing around with a 1 through 5 loop and can't remember why I ditched it. I'll check this option out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this works.

```
question_id = xxx
stats = ResponseItem.select('score, count(id) as count').
                     where(question_id: question_id).
                     joins('RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT "1" AS score UNION SELECT "2" UNION SELECT "3" UNION SELECT "4" UNION SELECT "5") as scores on score = answer_text').
                     group('score')
scale = stats.reduce({}) do |memo, answer_count|
  memo.merge(answer_count.score.to_i => answer_count.count)
end
```

Comment: I hadn't considered doing outer joins for some reason, seems like a good idea. Although all the other tables (the ones I obfuscated in my question above) may rule this out (need to restrict results by a complex set of which clients they are assigned to - when a user is logged in). Thanks.

Comment: There's no stopping you from doing all of the inner joins before the outer join to give you your `where`, but the code would be much harder to read. Personally I'd do it in 2 queries (the first being the hand-waved `xxx`), but you'd want to check performance/memory usage with real data before deciding.